# What is the most Pythonic way to change dir with a function that is both decorator and context manager?

Tags: python, decorator

I've written a function that operates as both a context manager and a function.

My function works back to Python 2.6 and works against this test:

```
@cd('/')
def test_cd_decorator():
    assert os.getcwd() == '/'

def test_cd():
    old = os.getcwd()
    with cd('/'):
        assert os.getcwd() == '/'
    assert os.getcwd() == old
    test_cd_decorator()
    assert os.getcwd() == old

test_cd()
```

What is the most Pythonic solution?

Comment: What is your failure?

Comment: @WayneWerner There is no failure. I had a solution for this, but wanted to know how other people solve it.

Comment: I've edited your question to make it clear you're simply looking for the most Pythonic solution.

Comment: You do't post the code for `cd`. Are you looking for a Pythonic version of that function, or a Pythonic version of the tests?

Comment: Take a look at the `mock` library, which defines a `patch` function that acts as both a context manager and function/class decorator.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about improving existing code - codereview.stackexchange.com is a better place for questions like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know there is such library that does what you need. So I created one.

```
import functools
import os

class cd:
    def __init__(self, path):
        self.path = path
    def __enter__(self):
        self.old = os.getcwd()
        os.chdir(self.path)
        return self
    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, tb):
        os.chdir(self.old)
    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            with self:
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
```